# foursquare api is not narrowing results by categoryid

Tags: api, foursquare

I am attempting to use the foursquare api and am running into an issue where it will not narrow my results down to a list of categoryid's.  Can someone look at what I am passing in and let me know why the results are not narrowed down to the list of categories I provide?

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=checkin&ll=33.54,-84.24&radius=2000&categoryid=4bf58dd8d48988d1a7941735,52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b53

Thanks!

Comment: I have searched on the web (including stackoverflow) and have seen some people state they had good results placing the categoryids as the first parameter after search.  I have tried that among other things.  I did not include my oauth in the above since it would need to be regenerated for anyone else that was going to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this occurs when there are no venues matching the categories you've specified in the region.